# Python OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: python, opencv

I'm creating an application that uses OpenCV and other Python libraries to grab a region of someone's screen, and compare it to a template image. This code works perfectly until the "dst" line. At that point I recieve the error

> 141 825 3 141 825 3 OpenCV Error:
>   Sizes of input arguments do not match
>   (The operation is neither 'array op
>   array' (where arrays have the same
>   size and the same number of channels),
>   nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op
>   array')

Normally I would think this error arose because of different image sizes. But they are the exact same. I confirmed this by printing their heights, widths, and depths. As you can see above, they are identical.

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui
import os
import sys
import time
import Image
import ImageGrab

import cv2
import numpy as np

player = cv2.imread('./images/bg_eagle_player.png')

#User Settings:
SaveDirectory=r'C:\Users\something\somethingeelse'

while (1):
    img=ImageGrab.grab()
    saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'test.png')
    img.save(saveas)

    img = cv2.imread('test.png')
    player_border = img[436:577, 378:1203]

    height, width, depth = player.shape
    print height, width, depth

    height, width, depth = player_border.shape
    print height, width, depth

    dst = cv2.addWeighted(player,0.7,img,0.3,0)

    cv2.imshow('image',dst)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `img` and `player` images appear to be of different sizes.

Comment: The height width and depth (141 825 3, 141 825 3) of the two images suggest otherwise.

Comment: You check `img` and `player_border` are the same size, but you call `addWeighted()` on `img` and `player`. Is that the same size too?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Embarrassing that it had me stumped.

Comment: Hey, I once spent about four hours trying to fix a database program because I had left out a pair of parentheses. Stared at the code forever, telling myself I was committing to the database, when I wasn't actually calling the method!